# Instalar Phalcon Devtools en OSX con Mamp

Tags: php, macos, phalcon

Estoy intentando instalar phalcon-devtools en OSX con MAMP y Php 7.0.10 pero no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar. 
Me bajado la extensión [phalcon.so](https://github.com/majksner/php-phalcon-mamp/tree/master/php7.0.10) para la versión correspondiente de mi php y la subí en:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/lib/php/extensions

Cuando hago un **phpinfo()** me muestra que la extensión ha sido cargada correctamente así que sigo con la instalación **[phalcon-devtools](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools#installation-via-git)**.

Tras la instalación cuando intento usarlo escribiendo cualquier comando me salta un error indicándome que la extensión no ha sido instalada:

> ERROR: Phalcon extension isn't installed, follow these instructions to install it: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende la configuración puede que tengas varios php.ini, uno para CLI y otro para WebServer

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

chequeá si figura el mismo

Si no es así, agregá la carga de la extensión de phalcon a ese php.ini que sería el específico para consola.

Esto me ha pasado en servidores.

Comment: Gracias Lyoneel. Lo hice en su día, pero si era eso.